# How to reformat bad date data on load infile

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to reformat the date from my csv file to the yyyy-mm-dd format that mysql requires. The file that I was given has the format '10/22/1988'. Here is the code that I am working with so far.

```
**load data infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Driver.csv'
into table Driver
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 rows
(DriverID,DriverFirst,DriverLast,SSN,@DOB,@StartDate,@EndDate,Address,City,State,Zip,Phone,Cell,Mileage,@Review,DrivingRecord)
SET
DOB = DATE_FORMAT(@DOB, "%Y %M %D"),
StartDate = DATE_FORMAT(@DOB, "%Y %M %D"),
EndDate = nullif(DATE_FORMAT(@EndDate, "%Y %M %D"),''),
Review = nullif(DATE_FORMAT(@Review, "%Y %M %D"),'')
;**
```

And this is how I have built my table:

```
create table Driver
(
    DriverID smallint not null auto_increment,
    DriverFirst varchar(20) not null,
    DriverLast varchar(20) not null,
    SSN varchar(9) not null,
    DOB date not null,
    StartDate date not null,
    EndDate date null,
    Address varchar(30) not null,
    City varchar(30) not null,
    State varchar(2) not null,
    Zip varchar(6) not null,
    Phone varchar(10) not null,
    Cell varchar(10) not null,
    Mileage decimal(3,2) null,
    Review date null,
    DrivingRecord char(1) not null,
    constraint pk_Drivers primary key clustered (DriverID asc)
);
```

MySQL throws an error if the cell is empty so I have been working with the nullif() function.

Comment: Try with the nullif on the inside rather than the outside of your query. So you check for nulls prior to the date_format.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
str_to_date(@whatever, '%c/%d/%Y')
```

You are converting some random format into the standard "DATE" format, so you need str_to_date. Also ensure the source format actual match your input data, so in this case you need %c/%d/%Y.